# how to use another field without primary key in a join query of magento

Tags: php, magento

```
$this->select->from(array('tip'=>$this->_tipTable))
     ->joinLeft(array('prodname'=>$this->_prodTable),'prodname.item_id = tip.entity_id',array('*'))
     ->where('tip.`reserved_order_id` IS NULL AND tip.`items_count` > 0');
```

I just given like it is working but it is not giving exactly for my requirement i need to check

```
prodname.quote_id = tip.entity_id'
```

here quote_id is not primary key and it returns an error.

plese help me out of here. i want to check another field which is not a primary key?

thanks in advance!!

Comment: What types of $this and $this->select variables?
Maybe instead of the where function better will be using the next code
$this->addFieldToFilter('tip.reserved_order_id', 'notnull')
    ->addFieldToFilter('tip.items_count', array('gt' => 0));

Comment: What is the error when you try to join on `quote_id`?